# Scrapy parser. A bit sophisticated

Tags: python, web-scraping, twisted, scrapy

I need to parse all articles from one site. There is 1000+ shops in this site.
To get any one article I need a id_shop in cookies. I do that by Requests module
To get all 1000+ id_shops I need to parse Ajax forms.
Then I run 1000+ spiders for each shop this way:

```
def setup_crawler(domain):
    spider = MySpider(domain=domain)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()
```

So I have .py script which do all that steps and I run it by `python MySpider.py`. Everything works.
The broplem is: I can't run my spider simultaneously with another one's. I'm following that rule(listed here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html):

```
for domain in ['scrapinghub.com', 'insophia.com']:
    setup_crawler(domain)
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

Instead of setup_crawler() I use MySpider.run().
I got that MySpider waits anothers.
I have two quastions:
1. How to run MySpider simultaneously with another one's?
2. I want to parse id_shops from ajax and run 1000+ spiders for each id_shop in one spider. Is it possible?

Comment: This might be a good read: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Concurrency/99Bottles

Comment: "Instead of setup_crawler() I use MySpider.run()" - Why do you do that?   That code from best practices works perfectly.

Comment: because MySpider is not just one spider. It's .py script. Is has run() method. look:     
    def run(self, id_task):                                                                                                                                      
        self.id_task = id_task     
        self.stores = self.find_shops()                                                                                                          
        self.parse_next_shop(self)